# Teamcity - intermittent clearcase snapshot error - reading changes

Tags: windows-xp, teamcity, clearcase, snapshot

Getting the following error in the Project View against projects reading changes from a clearcase snapshot

```
Error collecting changes for VCS root 'VS Root Name'
jetbrains.buildServer.vcs.VcsException: Process cleartool lshistory -eventid -recurse -    since 22-December-2010.16:42:08 -fmt %u#--#%Nd#--#%En#--#%m#--#%Vn#--#%o#--#%e#--#%Nc#-    -#%[activity]p###----###\n \\server\D$\path\vob returns -1 

jetbrains.buildServer.vcs.VcsException: Error collecting changes for VCS root 'VS Root Name' 
jetbrains.buildServer.vcs.VcsException: Process cleartool lshistory -eventid -recurse -    since 22-December-2010.16:42:08 -fmt %u#--#%Nd#--#%En#--#%m#--#%Vn#--#%o#--#%e#--#%Nc#--#%[activity]p###----###\n \\server\D$\path\vob returns -1 
at     jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.clearcase.ClearCaseSupport.collectChangesWithConnection(ClearCaseSupport.java:622) 
at jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.clearcase.ClearCaseSupport.collectChanges(ClearCaseSupport.java:612)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to troubleshoot that kind of error is to **execute the same command in a shell sesssion** (DOS here), **and see the detailed error message that `cleartool` will produce**.
(TeamCity only display the fact that the command has failed)

Possible errors are:

- no albd process on the server where the snapshot view is
- UNC path problem (can you make a simple '`dir \\server\D$\path\vob`'?)
- right issue (are you using the right account to query this view)
- ...